# R: TTR: Sorting by market cap

Tags: r

I am trying to sort stock symbols by market cap
I tried the code below, but the list did not sort properly. Is there a simple way to remove the $ and convert the M and B into numeric?

```
library(TTR)
listings <- stockSymbols() 
listings <- listings[order(as.numeric(listings$MarketCap),decreasing=TRUE),]
head(listings,20)
```

I would be grateful for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There may be packages which provide functions for converting, e.g. `"$23.93M"` to `239600000.00`, but here's one approach using base R functions:

```
listings$MktCap <- as.numeric(
  sub("\\$(\\d+(\\.\\d+)?)[A-Z]?", "\\1", listings$MarketCap)) * 
  ifelse(gsub("[^A-Z]", "", listings$MarketCap) == "M", 1e6,
         ifelse(gsub("[^A-Z]", "", listings$MarketCap) == "B", 1e9, 1.0)) 

head(listings[order(listings$MktCap, decreasing = TRUE),], 5)
#     Symbol                    Name LastSale MarketCap IPOyear     Sector
#382    AAPL              Apple Inc.    94.69  $525.02B    1980 Technology
#1637  GOOGL           Alphabet Inc.   717.29  $493.72B      NA Technology
#1636   GOOG           Alphabet Inc.   695.85  $478.97B    2004 Technology
#2238   MSFT   Microsoft Corporation    51.18   $404.8B    1986 Technology
#6664    XOM Exxon Mobil Corporation    81.23  $338.16B      NA     Energy
#
#                                            Industry Exchange       MktCap
#382                           Computer Manufacturing   NASDAQ 525020000000
#1637 Computer Software: Programming, Data Processing   NASDAQ 493720000000
#1636 Computer Software: Programming, Data Processing   NASDAQ 478970000000
#2238         Computer Software: Prepackaged Software   NASDAQ 404800000000
#6664                        Integrated oil Companies     NYSE 338160000000
```

---

Briefly,

- `sub("\\$(\\d+(\\.\\d+)?)[A-Z]?", "\\1", listings$MarketCap)` extracts just the decimal number part of `MarketCap`, e.g. `525.02` from `$525.02B`; and the result is passed to `as.numeric`
- `gsub("[^A-Z]", "", listings$MarketCap)` removes everything except capital letters, which should only be `B` or `M`, as far as I can see
- Using nested `ifelse` statements, the result of the above expression will map `"B"` to `1e9`, `"M"` to `1e6`, and all else to 1

At this point, `MktCap` should be the correct numeric representation of `MarketCap`, and sorting is straightforward.